Adding edge to an `igraph` in `R`
There are a few similar posts (like this one and this too), but my question might be more basic for the igraph package functionality.
This is the minimal example that generates a simple graph:
library(MASS)
library(pcalg)
library(igraph)

# Some variance-covariance
Corrs <- matrix(c(1.0,0.6,0.7,0.5,0.6,1.0,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.5,1.0,0.7,0.5,0.6,0.7,1.0), 4, 4)
SDs <- c(1.0,0.5,2.0,1.0)
Covs <- SDs %*% t(SDs) * Corrs

dat = as.data.frame(mvrnorm(100, mu=c(0,0,0,0), Sigma=Covs))

n = nrow(dat)
V = colnames(dat) # node names
pc1 = pc(suffStat=list(C=cor(dat), n=n),
    indepTest=gaussCItest, # indep.test: partial correlations
    alpha=0.05, labels=V, u2pd='retry')

gr = graph_from_graphnel(pc1@graph)

plot.igraph(gr, layout=layout_in_circle,
    vertex.label=V, vertex.shape='circle', vertex.size=30,
    vertex.label.cex=0.55, vertex.label.color='black',
    edge.arrow.size=0.6)

If I try to add an edge (for example, V2 —> V3) it ends with only that edge while others, "original" edges are gone:
gr = graph_from_graphnel(pc1@graph) + edge(2, 3, color='blue')

plot.igraph(gr, layout=layout_in_circle,
    vertex.label=V, vertex.shape='circle', vertex.size=30,
    vertex.label.cex=0.55, vertex.label.color='black',
    edge.arrow.size=0.6)

I also tried with the add_edges() function and got the same result.
So, how can I add an edge to the existing graph? And how can I mark that particular edge with different color (which I managed) and lty?

how did you use add_edges()? Please show your attempt

g <- gr |>
  set_edge_attr("color", value = "green") |>
  add_edges(c(2,3), color = "blue")

plot.igraph(g, layout=layout_in_circle,
            vertex.label=V, vertex.shape='circle', vertex.size=30,
            vertex.label.cex=0.55, vertex.label.color='black',
            edge.arrow.size=0.6)



You need to set the colour attributes for all existing edges before adding another edge (with colour attribute). Otherwise, the colour will be NA, and the edge will not be drawn.
You can see from the following:
 g <- gr |>
     #  set_edge_attr("color", value = "green") |>
     add_edges(c(2,3), color = "blue")

E(g)[[]]
    
#+ 6/6 edges from 4b001d7 (vertex names):
#  tail head tid hid weight color
#1   V1   V2   1   2      1  <NA>
#2   V1   V3   1   3      1  <NA>
#3   V2   V4   2   4      1  <NA>
#4   V3   V1   3   1      1  <NA>
#5   V3   V4   3   4      1  <NA>
#6   V2   V3   2   3     NA  blue



This is a good demonstration of using add_edges. I am wondering if OP misused it. Probably it would be better if you could attach the usage from igraph help manual and show OP how it should be applied.

@ThomasIsCoding - thanks. Hope my explanation helps.

yes, it looks really good. I believe OP would get help from it.

This is great indeed. Thanks. May I please ask if the line type can be specified too or not?

Yes, add another command: set_edge_attr("lty", value = "solid") |>, and then add , lty="dashed" to the add_edges() command. The principle is the same as for the colours. You have to set the attribute for all edges first. add_edges(c(2,3), color = "blue", lty="dashed")
